# C2DM Push notification message not received

Tags: android, android-c2dm, socketexception

Im trying to implement the C2DM - Push notification by vogellas.I dont receive any message device/emulator though the code returns 200.Log cat error 'request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol'.What has to be done?

Comment: followed this tutorial..http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: @Satheesh,read the question properly, he has developed code using that link only.

Comment: see this http://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/Setting-up-Android-Push and also this one https://github.com/tomasmalmsten/c2dm-android-pilot

Comment: @all i think some one who has tried c2dm already can help me...